# Using @font-face with an SVG font embedded in the current HTML page

Tags: html, css, svg, webfonts

I have a standalone HTML document I want to distribute, without any external dependencies. I'm using a non-standard font in this document that only some of my users will have installed.

For those users that do not have the font installed, I am including a copy of the font in an embedded SVG document at the top of the `<body>`. (I'm using a one-glyph font for this example, the real document is using a complete font.)

```html
<svg style="display: none;"><defs>
  <font id="MyFontElement">
    <font-face font-family="MyFont" />
    <glyph unicode="A" horiz-adv-x="950" d="M0,0L0,100L100,100L100,200L0,200L0,300L100,300L100,400L200,400L200,500L300,500L300,600L400,600L600,600L600,500L700,500L700,400L800,400L800,300L900,300L900,200L800,200L800,100L900,100L900,0L600,0L600,100L700,100L700,200L800,200L800,300L100,300L100,200L200,200L200,100L300,100L300,0L0,0M300,400L600,400L600,500L300,500L300,400Z" />    
  </font>
</defs></svg>
```

SVG fonts do not look as nice as ordinary fonts, so I only want the SVG font to be used if the font is not installed locally. If the font was defined in an external SVG document, I could use it at a lower priority than the locally-installed font like this: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/HANsP/))

```html
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: "My Font";
    src: local("My Font"), url("fonts.svg#MyFontElement") format("svg");
  }
</style>
<p style="font: 3em 'My Font';">
    Alphabet
</p>
```

> [image: screenshot]

Unfortunately, none of the obvious variations seem to work for a font in the current document: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/xX6Bv/))

```css
  src: local("My Font"),
       url("./#MyFontElement") format("svg"),
       url("./#MyFontElement"),
       url("#MyFontElement") format("svg"),
       url("#MyFontElement");
```

Even without a `@font-face` declaration, the font is already available in the document as `MyFont`, the `font-family` specified in the `<font-face />`. However, this will be used at a *higher* priority than a native font named `MyFont`, so it is not an solution.

I hoped that I might be able to refer to it as `local("MyFont")`... ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/X78SN/))

```css
  src: local("My Font"), /* local */
       local("MyFont"); /* embedded */
```

...but that doesn't work either.

I could give the embedded font a different name and use it at a lower priority, `style="font-family: LocalFont, EmbeddedFont"`, but I'm allowing users to import snippets from local files into the document and those local files will refer to the font only by the standard name. It would be possible to rewrite these references when they're imported, but I don't like that solution.

How do I refer to an SVG font embedded in the current document from a `@font-face` declaration?

Comment: Readers should be aware that SVG font support has been removed from Google Chrome, and was never implemented in Mozilla Firefox. Apple still appears to be maintaining it in Safari, however.

Comment: Apparently Firefox does currently have support for SVG-based glyphs... embedded inside of OpenType files! Oy...

Answer (score 5):

Convert the font to a data URI and embedded it in the CSS declaration: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/eCtKa/))

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: "My Font";
  src: url("data:application/octet-stream;base64,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") format("svg");
}
</style>
<p style="font: 3em 'My Font';">
    Alphabet
</p>
```

There's one caveat: you can't use an ID specifier (`#MyFont`) with a data URI like this. Therefore you can only have a single font in the encoded file, rather than having multiple and referring to them individually. (Not that you'd want to; duplicating the data for multiple embedded fonts in the declaration for each font would be a huge waste of space.)

Comment: Good idea, thanks, this work well! I've edited your post to include an example and a caveat I noted. However, I'm not going to accept this answer yet in case there *is* a solution that allows me to refer to a font in a normal embedded SVG document.

Comment: Rather than using fragments wouldn't you just declare another font-face block with the other font?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm going to do. It would be a bad decision to use fragments, but if it worked I might do it if I were feeling terribly lazy. I wanted to warn any other lazy readers that it won't work;  it wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: You shouldn't use "application/octet-stream" if it's an svgfont, it should be "image/svg+xml". AFAIK you *can* use an ID specifier, at least I'm pretty sure that worked in Opera last I tried it. And you should always use an ID specifier with svgfonts, unless you are comfortable with depending on unspecified behavior. Here's a fixed up fiddle showing how it should look: http://jsfiddle.net/fPg3z/

Comment: @ErikDahlström The WC3 working draft for CSS3 Fonts told me that "*in the case of SVG fonts, the URL points to an element within a document containing SVG font definitions. If the element reference is omitted, a reference to the first defined font is implied*". When I try to specify a fragment on the data URL, it breaks in Chrome. Oh dear...

Comment: Ah, hadn't seen that bit in the CSS3 Fonts draft, I'll file a bug for Opera to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the local font name first in the css, then the embedded font name:

```css
p {
    font-family: MyFontLocalName, MyFontEmbeddedName;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/xX6Bv/5/

If the `MyFontLocalName` is installed on the user's computer, that font will be used, otherwise `MyFontEmbeddedName` will be used.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it won't work for me. I'm sorry for not mentioning this in my post initially: I'm allowing users to import snippets from local documents that are referring to the font by its standard name, so this won't work for them. :( (I was referring to fonts by different names before, "X" and "X Embedded".)

Comment: @Jeremy - Tricky.  I've actually thought about this some before.  The best I've come up with would be an ugly hack and involve JavaScript:  Put a piece of text into a span with the desired font and a fallback font at a very large size, Eg `font-size: 200px; font-family: MyEmbeddableFont, Arial`.  Check the width of the span against the expected width of the test font.  If the width is off, dynamically load the font.

Comment: Note this implementation `glyph` has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/glyph