# Font in an SVG sometimes doesn't load in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

On a site I work on, we use SVG for the logo. I've noticed a few times that the logo occasionally doesn't load the correct font when it renders in Google Chrome. I haven't been able to replicate this anywhere else, but it has happened frequently enough that I'm concerned it could be happening to other Chrome users.

You can see the SVG here: https://jsfiddle.net/rmlumley/8n5Lrq9z/

I'm loading in the SVG via CSS as a background image for the h1 in this code:

```
<li class="home"><a href="/" rel="home"><h1><span>Morgridge Institute for Research</span></h1></a></li>
```

When I load the SVG directly in the browser, it always works and loads in the correct font. That said, occasionally when it loads in on the page in Chrome - the font looks wrong. I've uploaded how it renders incorrectly.

[image]

Is this a known issue with Chrome or any suggested work-arounds so that this doesn't happen? Is there something inherently wrong with my SVG code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SVG is not using any font other than the default browser font (normally Times New Roman).  That's because the SVG is not specifying a different font.

You may be thinking that the following in the SVG is changing the font:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Garamond,Baskerville,Baskerville Old Face,Hoefler Text,Times New Roman,serif";
  }
</style>
```

But this is doing nothing.  It should be something like:

```
#logo {
  font-family: "Garamond,Baskerville,Baskerville Old Face,Hoefler Text,Times New Roman,serif";
}
```

But even if you do that, the only users that will be seeing "Garamond", "Baskerville", "Baskerville Old Face" or "Hoefler Text", will be users that have those fonts installed on their computer.  **You** may be seeing Garamond (if you have that font installed), but most people will still just be seeing Times New Roman or whatever they have their default font set to.

If you want to use another font, then you would need to fix your `@font-face`
declaration and [use Data URIs to embed your font in the SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438150/using-font-face-with-an-svg-font-embedded-in-the-current-html-page).

But there is a much better solution to this problem however.  And that is to convert your text to outlines (paths). Then all your font worries disappear, and you are guaranteed to have the correct representation of your logo font, in everybody's browser.

Comment: Is there a tool to convert text to paths?

Comment: Any vector editor. Eg. Illustrator, Sketch, Inkscape. etc

Comment: I updated the codepen to reflect the new path only SVG. Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you kept it as it was. Now that you've changed it, people who read this question in the future, can no longer see what the SVG originally looked like - making this answer less useful.

Comment: Good point. Switched it to the original. This is the new code: https://codepen.io/rmlumley/pen/XgomRV

Comment: Object to path is the way to go. An svg as vector doesn't need a font family: https://community.glowforge.com/t/inkscape-tutorial-text-to-outlines/2996