# SVG issue in <img> Html

Tags: svg

Trying to upload a Logo in SVG on website, but in my PC is looks fine but in others pc or mobile it loads with different font.
I read very articles but could not find how to solve this.

CODEPEN:

> https://codepen.io/miguelfernandesidesign/project/editor/AnpmmW

Comment: it may be the font family you are using is not accesible in other computers

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. how can solve this. I already try here very possible solutions but no luck

Comment: Please post a minimal verifiable test case in the question itself. That codepen is chock full of extra stuff.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977035/using-system-font-in-svg#48981710